# Is there a way to change device configuration under WinUSB?

Tags: usb, winusb

I have a multi-function USB device. There's no driver (yet). I want to write an application that talks to just one of its interfaces. It would seem that WinUSB would be perfect for the job, but there's one snag: I need to change the device configuration before I can access the interface.

Is there some way to have WinUSB (or any other part of the system) set the device configuration at the start? I won't need to change it, I just want it to not be configuration zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can do that with WinUSB.

You might look into using [libusb](http://libusb.info), since it has a function named [libusb_set_configuration](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__dev.html#ga186593ecae576dad6cd9679f45a2aa43) that should do what you want.  However, I do not know whether that function actually works on Windows.

Comment: I think you're probably right here. My understanding is that libusb is bundled with a kernel driver. I do know that only a kernel driver can change a device configuration.

Comment: libusb can use multiple different kernel drivers, including WinUSB, libusbK, and some others I think.  One of those drivers might allow you to change the configuration, but I haven't actually tried it.

Comment: Definitely not WinUSB. USBccgp can change configuration, but only to a hard-coded value from the registry. I worked with Microsoft's engineers once to build a driver that could dynamically choose configuration. It worked by interposing a filter driver ahead of USBccgp, determining which configuration should be used, and actually altering the registry value that USBccgp would then use. If the desired configuration changed after that, the shim driver would reset the USB port to force the whole process to run again.

Answer (score 0):

WinUSB will not let you set device configuration. The usual method is to use USBccgp, specify the "OriginalConfigurationValue" registry value, and then run WinUSB on top of USBccgp.

To be clear, you *cannot* change the configuration on the fly using Microsoft-supplied drivers. WinUSB doesn't deal with configurations and USBccgp will only set a hard-coded configuration. If you need to select your configuration at runtime, you'll need to write your own driver and it will need to be a kernel driver (not a user-space driver).